# does editing the email address policy in Exchange 2010 remove addresses?

Tags: exchange-2010

Our current email address policy in exchange 2010 has way too many email address formats so I'd like to trim it down.

If I edit the policy and remove one of the formats, will that remove the corresponding addresses from my existing users, or will their extra addresses remain?

Ideally, I want them all to remain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has not removed the addresses for users when I have done this in the past. Obviously, it will not create them for new accounts added after the policy is removed.

As in all things, you should test this for yourself to be sure

Answer (score -1):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232171.aspx

Look at the "Behavior of Recipient Policies" section, it explains what happens when you modify these policies in Exchange 2010.

Comment: yes, when modifying a policy and saving it, the policy still exists and updates any recipient effected by the policy. When removing a policy, the policy no longer exists and Exchange cannot enforce a policy that does not exist so the address associated with that policy remain.

Comment: I already saw that page and it does not address my question. Also, simply linking to content without summarizing what the linked content says is frowned upon on stack exchange.

Comment: Hi Longneck, Email Address Policies are additive only, they never remove existing addresses from a mail-enabled object.